# Cannot obtain Metadata when using WCFTestClient tool

Tags: wcf, ssl, wsdl

I have a WCF service `https://payments.acompany.com/WebBridge10/WebBridge10.svc?`.
I can open it in the browser, now I want to test it with WCFTestClient tool. After I add the wsdl path to it, I got:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://payments.acompany.com/WebBridge10/WebBridge10.svc?wsdl If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: https://payments.acompany.com/WebBridge10/WebBridge10.svc?wsdl Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://payments.acompany.com/WebBridge10/WebBridge10.svc?wsdl'. An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://payments.acompany.com/WebBridge10/WebBridge10.svc?wsdl. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.HTTP GET Error URI: https://payments.acompany.com/WebBridge10/WebBridge10.svc?wsdl There was an error downloading 'https://payments.acompany.com/WebBridge10/WebBridge10.svc?wsdl'. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Also I added the service reference to the Visual Studio project, the node(***ValidateBTNandProceePayment***) shows a + sign on the left. But the other services are showing a locker icon. See the image below.

[image]

Why?

Comment: Could you share your configuration file?
For the second question, the plus icon means a new file you added to the solution and it's not committed to TFS

Comment: I haven't set up the configuration file. As WCFTestClient tool doesn't need it.

Comment: Does your service does not have a configuration file?
You must add a serviceMetadata to the configuration in order to expose wsdl

Comment: The thing is I consume the service. Another guy wrote the service, he only gave me the wsdl uri.

Comment: By the way, I need send data to the service. Maybe WCFTestClient tool is only for retrieving data to the service?

Comment: You can send data with WCFTestClient, you just need to fill the object with right values. Is ther any enum in the object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87815/discussion-between-love-and-ricardo-pontual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, because it is a https service. We need to set up tls 1.2 in Fiddler. So the solution is download Fiddler and click "Tools"=>"Fiddler options"=>"https".

[image: fiddler]

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have been self answered already, but for anyone who doesn't want use Fiddler as workaround this solution might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53503187/593617